# Spring Cloud Data Flow Failed to upload the package. Package [test-stream-comments:1.0.0] in Repository [local] already exists

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have created a few streams in Spring cloud data flow. I deployed them and they were running smoothly. Then I undeployed them and when I try to re deploy the streams by clicking "Deploy Streams", I get a red error prompt which says `"Spring Cloud Data Flow Failed to upload the package. Package [test-stream-comments:1.0.0] in Repository [local] already exists."`

Does this mean I must destroy the stream and recreate and deploy the stream again? That defeats the purpose of deploying and undeploying the streams via a click of the button?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try run spring-cloud-dataflow-shell and run:

`stream undeploy facebook-stream-comments`.

Then try deploy this stream again from web UI.

**update.**

I continued research and find other, low-level way to fix this issue:

I connected to MySql db and deleted all records, linked with bad package:

```
delete from `dataflow`.`skipper_status` where (`id` = '...');
delete from `dataflow`.`skipper_info` where (`id` = '...');
delete from `dataflow`.`skipper_app_deployer_data` where (`id` = '...');
delete from `dataflow`.`skipper_release` where (`id` = '...');
delete from `dataflow`.`skipper_package_file` where (`id` = '...');
delete from `dataflow`.`skipper_package_metadata` where (`id` = '...');
```

and restart `spring-cloud-skipper-server.jar

But this way is hardway and incorrect (probably).

Comment: I did "stream undeploy facebook-stream-comments" and then start it again on web ui. it works

Comment: Rebooting my docker-compose cluster led to the same error. It was solved by the shell command you suggested. Any idea what the underlying issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Another resolution if above doesn't work is below:

1. select * from skipper_release where name = 'streamName' order by id
   desc, get value from info_id column and go to next step
2. select * from skipper_info where id = info_id (from above step),
   get value from status_id column and go to next step
3. select * from skipper_status where id = status_id (from above step),
   here check the value of status_code column and if it is other than
   DELETED, then follow next step. Get value from id column and go to
   next step
4. update skipper_status set status_code = 'DELETED' where id = {id}
   (from above step)
5. start SCDF shell, go to D:\sys_apps_01\scdf, open CMD and run
   following command: java -jar
   spring-cloud-dataflow-shell-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar
6. Run command: stream undeploy --name {streamName}
7. After this try to deploy the stream.